# No cards available for configuration - PulseAudio

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I cannot hear any sounds. I have pavucontrol installed and in the `Configuration` tab, it says "No cards available for configuration". Everything is set to dummy output.

I don't know what caused this, I tried reinstalling everything pulseaudio related and restarted but no luck.

When the sound did work, I used to hear this crackling sound so I ran this command `echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save` which worked fine before but now it gives me an error saying: `/usr/bin/tee: /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save: No such file or directory`

That could be where the problem is coming from. Some other things:

```
$ aplay -l
aplay: device_list:274: no soundcards found...
```

```
$ pacmd list-cards
0 card(s) available.
```

I have tried a whole load of things from the internet but nothing works. Please help me.

**Edit:** I found out that I tried to install realtek drivers. I tried with these ones to be specific [image: Realtek]

I remember `make install` giving me some errors.

I tried doing `make uninstall` afterwards tho [image: This is what it gave me]

I rebooted afterwards but nothing.

**Edit 2:** The `/sys/module/snd_hda_intel` folder is missing. This has to be the root of the problem. Is there a way I can get that back?

Comment: What is your OS? Why would you install a driver that is marked as for kernels versions under 3.18?

Comment: It is Xubuntu 20.04. I didn't notice it when I was downloading that I was having problems with not being able to change output device in a game. I ended up with a bigger problem

Comment: The major problem still seems to be `/sys/module/snd_hda_intel/` not existing now whereas it did exist before this happened

Comment: `snd_hda_intel` is available in all kernels, it doesn't require installation. Tryintg to insall some crap you could make things worse. Generally maybe your sound device is not supported by Linux.

Comment: It was working perfectly before I tried the realtek drivers and that folder existed. And now that folder doesn't exist

Comment: Why would you install really old unsupported drivers if all worked perfectly? I suggest to reinstall kernel.

Comment: How do I reinstall the kernal?

Comment: Here is the solution I used to fix the issue: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/573793/pulseaudio-says-no-cards-available-for-configuration-but-there-are-at-least-two/652092#652092

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suggest to reinstall kernel. Run in a terminal

```
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-$(uname -r)
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-$(uname -r)
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)
```

Comment: Thank you so much man :)

Comment: In my case, there was an issue with the virtualbox module crashing, I had to remove virtualbox using `sudo apt remove --purge virtualbox` then re-install the kernel