# How to reinstall sound drivers in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, sound, 20.04, ubuntu-drivers

I have tried everything. I have tried reinstalling alsa, alsa-base and pulse audio but still alsa shows no driver modules.
This is the output from
`inxi -SMA`

System:
Host: PrinzzUbuntu Kernel: 5.4.0-42-generic x86_64 bits: 64
Desktop: Gnome 3.36.4 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)

Machine:
Type: Laptop System: ASUSTeK product: GL553VE v: 1.0
serial: <superuser/root required>
Mobo: ASUSTeK model: GL553VE v: 1.0 serial: <superuser/root required>
UEFI: American Megatrends v: GL553VE.308 date: 04/29/2019

Audio:
Device-1: Intel CM238 HD Audio driver: N/A

Can somebody help me to fix this driver issue?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1262628/1021259  this thread resolved my issue