# Realtek driver installation gone wrong, audio and microphone stopped working

Tags: drivers, sound, 22.04, alsa, microphone

[Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS]
I messed up. I tried fixing the issue some ubuntu users seem to have, namely that the sound volume is way lower than on windows (even with over-amplification enabled). I wanted to install Realtek driver to see if it would work better. I followed the instructions, got an error, it didn't work. I downloaded a Linux driver (3.0), v 5.18rc8 from Realtek website. It's a .tar.bz2 package containing an installation guide inside. The steps are: extracting everything, running ./configure inside the extracted directory, running make, and make install. I got an error on the last step, but I don't remember the details of it, and I don't think I should try to recreate it at this point. But  after a reboot I found myself in a position that's worse.

1. Speakers and microphone don't work. All I get is 'Dummy output'.
2. `alsamixer` doesn't work. The terminal output is this:

```
ALSA lib confmisc.c:855:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_inum returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:422:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1334:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5701:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib control.c:1528:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL default
cannot open mixer: No such file or directory
```

I tried reinstalling `alsa-utils`. Didn't help.

3. System Profiler and Benchmark doesn't display any audio devices anymore. Same goes for PulseAudio. However, running `sudo lspci -v | grep -i audio` does show `00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)`
4. `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` returns `All the available drivers are already installed.`

I know it's probably annoying to answer questions like that, because basically I did it to myself. But I really don't know how to move forward from here and would very much appreciate some guidance.

**edit**
I booted to a previous kernel version and there everything works properly. From there I reinstalled the kernel I had been using, booted into it, and no luck. My latest kernel still doesn't have sound.

Comment: *"I followed the instructions"* what instructions? which driver did you install, and how?

Comment: @steeldriver Apologies, this should have been described clearly. I downloaded a Linux driver (3.0), v 5.18rc8 from [Realtek website](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/pc-audio-codecs-high-definition-audio-codecs-software). It's a .tar.bz2 package containing an installation guide inside. The steps are: extracting everything, running `./configure` inside the extracted directory, running `make`, and `make install`. I got an error on the last step, but I don't remember the details of it, and I don't think I should try to recreate it at this point

Comment: Thanks (although it would be better to [edit] that information into your question)  - did you execute any of the steps as root?

Comment: Yes, as this was suggested in the guide in case something doesn't execute properly, which, in hindsight, I probably shouldn't have listened to. But also, I now discovered [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1262628/no-cards-available-for-configuration-pulseaudio) by someone who shot themselves in the foot like I did, and people suggested reinstalling the kernel. Is that the way to go about it?

Comment: That looks like it *might* work - at least it should restore any common files that you have overwritten, I'm not sure if it will also get rid of other files (or indeed whether that matters)

Answer (score 0):

Soo, it turns out that the way out of this was reinstalling the kernel, following the way described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1262628/no-cards-available-for-configuration-pulseaudio), which is:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-$(uname -r)
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-$(uname -r)
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)
```

Many thanks to @steeldriver for taking their time to consider my question, as well as @Pilot6 for the original tip that ended up helping me.

**Edit**

Well, it was fun while it lasted. A week later a routine update brought everything back and more. Lost my sound again, my wifi stopped working and I started having issues with booting. Ended up reinstalling the OS.